# JavaScript math calculation

Tags: javascript

I need to perform a math calculation in JavaScript that I am unsure how to do so.

The formula is as follows:

```
result = (scale * weighting) / 2
```

where the result I will need to two decimal places.

Example formula that I need to do in JavaScript might be:

```
result = ((3 * 2) + (2 * 1.5)) / 2
```

I am also unsure if I have to also convert this to int.

Comment: <strike>Why not `result = (scale * weighting) / 2.0`?</strike>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
function algorithm(scale, weighting) {
   var result = (scale * weighting) / 2;
   return result.toFixed(2);
}
```

Or if you need an integer, [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
parseInt(result, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you want, but this might help:

```
result = Math.round(((scale * weighting) / 2) * 100) / 100;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kQpma/

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript everything number is a floating point number. No explicit type conversion needed.

ref : http://oreilly.com/javascript/excerpts/learning-javascript/javascript-datatypes-variables.html ( search for "The Number Data Type" )

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.